# How to generate a count of data for a particular dept for a specific days (3days, 4-7 days, 15 - 30 days) by using excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, pivot-table

[image]
[image: This the output which I got]

I am using the excel and pivot tables to generate the data

I want to show the number of issues logged by the department within the specific days.

Here are some formulas I've tried:

```
=IF(C328<=3,"THREE",IF(AND(C328>=4,C328<=7),"Four to seven","F"))
```

This one increments by date not the range:

```
=IF(C330<=3,"THREE",IF(AND(C330>=4,C330<=7),IF(C330<>C329,1,D329+1)))
```

Comment: What have you tried? `COUNTIFS()`?

Comment: =IF(C328<=3,"THREE",IF(AND(C328>=4,C328<=7),"Four to seven","F"))

Comment: =IF(C330<=3,"THREE",IF(AND(C330>=4,C330<=7),IF(C330<>C329,1,D329+1)))This one incremtns by date not the range

Comment: Can you paste the screenshot of Data or sample data to reproduce an example ?

Comment: Please refer the attached screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to return a **period name** (e.g. <3 Days, 4-7 Days, or 8-14 Days, etc.) in Column D based on the **Days Count**.

If so, you can use the **approximate match of VLOOKUP** to achieve that, but you will need to create a look up table first. See below screen-shot for details. Please note I have **named** the look up table as `Tbl_Period` in my solution.

[image: VLOOKUP and Pivot Table]

The formula in cell D2 is `=VLOOKUP(C2,Tbl_Period,2,TRUE)` and you simply drag it down to apply to the rest.

Then you can create a **pivot table** and set the values to be the **Count of Ticket ID**. You will need to manually drag the columns in the pivot table to display them in a desired order.

I did not see Team information in your second screenshot so I guess you may need to add a helper column to look up the Team based on Ticket ID and/or other criteria. Let me know if you have any question on this part. Cheers :)